# unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a code that is working fine in ie8 but in ie11 it's giving me  error -"unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference "while debugging. I am adding just a part of function. If you notice it is working fine for other elements just on isSpanish it is failing. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
 function callSchedule() {

document.getElementById("hideCallbackRow").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("scheduleCallBtn").disabled = true; 
var callbackDate = '';
var callbackCallTimeZone = '';
var callbackCallTime = '';
var spanish = '';
if(document.getElementById("fromDate1") && document.getElementById("requestedCallTimeZoneSelectedVal") && document.getElementById("requestedCallTimeSelectedVal")){
setCallbackValues();
callbackDate = document.getElementById("fromDate1").value;
callbackCallTimeZone = document.getElementById  ("requestedCallTimeZoneSelectedVal").value;
callbackCallTime = document.getElementById("requestedCallTimeSelectedVal").value;
spanish = document.getElementById("isSpanish").value;
```

Comment: Could you post the html?

Comment: Is there any other error before? `getElementById` is totally standard so, if you say the rest of the browsers do find the element, the problem is not exactly there.

Comment: I know you said this works in IE8, but have you definitely got the casing correct for `isSpanish`, i.e. a capital `S`? If it is getting to that line with no errors up to then, it can only be 1) the element has not been created yet, 2) It has been removed from the DOM or 3) there is a typo somewhere. Open F12 tools and when it errors on that line, go to console and try `document.getElementById("isSpanish")` to see if the element really is missing